# i want check box list alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net

![this is my output using checkbox list][1]

this is what i am getting from my own project...

but i really lokking like this checkbox list..![this is the sample i really want like this][2]

this is my output [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrlMq.png
i want like this model[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7VNP.png
what should i do i get like this checkbox list..

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" 
             RepeatColumns="4"
             RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
             runat="server" 
             style="font-size: large">
```

this is my source i need css and good alignment...
pls any one help me?

Comment: please upload the pic "this is my output using checkbox list" again as it is not visible to us..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layout` as follows

```
 <asp:checkboxlist runat="server" id="chkBoxList1" cssclass="chkBoxList" 
      repeatcolumns="4" repeatlayout="Table">
 </asp:checkboxlist>
```

with css

```
<style>
  .chkBoxList tr
  {
      height:24px;
  }

  .chkBoxList td
  {
      width:120px; /* or percent value: 25% */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: i want like that second image.